# JavaScript: Amend the Sentence

Tags: javascript, string, slice

I am having trouble below javaScript problem.

Question:
You have been given a string s, which is supposed to be a sentence. However, someone forgot to put spaces between the different words, and for some reason they capitalized the first letter of every word. Return the sentence after making the following amendments:

Put a single space between the words.
Convert the uppercase letters to lowercase.

Example

"CodefightsIsAwesome", the output should be "codefights is awesome";

"Hello", the output should be "hello".

My current code is:

[image]

Right now, my second for-loop just manually slices the parts from the string.
How can I make this dynamic and insert "space" in front of the Capital String?

Comment: what is the value of s

Comment: @JijoCleetus The input string?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/g` to match `A-Z` followed by one or more characters which are not `A-Z`, or character at end of string; chain `Array.prototype.map()` to call `.toLowerCase()` on matched words, `.join()` with parameter `" "` to include space character between matches at resulting string.

```js
var str = "CodefightsIsAwesome";
var res = str.match(/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/g).map(word => word.toLowerCase()).join(" ");
console.log(res);
```

Alternatively, as suggested by @FissureKing, you can use `String.prototype.repalce()` with `.trim()` and `.toLowerCase()` chained

```js
var str = "CodefightsIsAwesome";
var res = str.replace(/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/g, word => word + ' ').trim().toLowerCase();
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Maybe `*` instead of `+`, to allow for one-letter words?

Comment: @nnnnnn See updated post. Substituted `[^A-Z]` for `[a-z]` to match characters which are not uppercase letters.

Comment: So if the input was `"ThereIsNobodyCrazierThanI"`?

Comment: @nnnnnn `/[A-Z][^A-Z]+|.$/g`

Comment: @nnnnnn Got it.

Comment: Honest question: why `match`/`map`/`join` when you could accomplish the same using a single `str.replace(...)`?

Comment: @FissureKing Did not initially consider `.replace()`. `.toLowerCase()` would still need to be called, and space character concatenated, which `.map()` and `.join()` return, respectively.

Comment: I'm not saying your approach is wrong.  I just see it as a bit more readable to do something like `str => str.replace(/[A-Z][^A-Z]+/g, word => word + ' ').trim().toLowerCase()`.  Except, if this weren't a SO comment, I would not chain three methods in a single line :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than coding a loop, I'd do it in one line with a (reasonably) simple string replacement:

```js
function amendTheSentence(s) {
  return s.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(m) { return " " + m.toLowerCase() })
          .replace(/^ /, "");
}

console.log(amendTheSentence("CodefightsIsAwesome"));
console.log(amendTheSentence("noCapitalOnFirstWord"));
console.log(amendTheSentence("ThereIsNobodyCrazierThanI"));
```

That is, match any uppercase letter with the regular expression `/[A-Z]/`, replace the matched letter with a space plus that letter in lowercase, then remove any space that was added at the start of the string.

Further reading:

- [String `.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score -1):

We can loop through once.

The below assumes the very first character should always be capitalized in our return array.  If that is not true, simply remove the first `if` block from below.

For each character after that, we check to see if it is capitalized.  If so, we add it to our return array, prefaced with a space.  If not, we add it as-is into our array.

Finally, we join the array back into a string and return it.

```js
const sentence = "CodefightsIsAwesome";

const amend = function(s) {
  ret = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    const char = s[i];
    if (i === 0) {
      ret.push(char.toUpperCase());
    } else if (char.toUpperCase() === char) {
      ret.push(` ${char.toLowerCase()}`);
    } else {
      ret.push(char);
    }
  }
  return ret.join('');
};

console.log(amend(sentence));
```